# Underscore filtering multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Say this is my data, how could I use Underscore to filter the data to only keep the nested part by tax_rank, but keep the object structure?

I am trying to create a heatmap that when you choose from a drop down it re-draws the heatmap by tax_rank.  I am new to Underscore and the .filter .pluck and .map utilities look very helpful but I can not seem to get the chaining correct.

```
let data = [
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
            {
              "taxon": 817,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 72,
              "count_norm": 1283,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 818,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 208,
              "count_norm": 3708,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 820,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 41,
              "count_norm": 731,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 821,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 3490,
              "count_norm": 62226,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 823,
              "parent": 375288,
              "count": 120,
              "count_norm": 2139,
              "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 832,
              "parent": 204431,
              "count": 12,
              "count_norm": 213,
              "tax_name": "Fibrobacter",
              "tax_rank": "genus"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 841,
              "parent": 186803,
              "count": 1285,
              "count_norm": 22911,
              "tax_name": "Roseburia",
              "tax_rank": "genus"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 842,
              "parent": 841,
              "count": 11,
              "count_norm": 196,
              "tax_name": "Roseburia cecicola",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 853,
              "parent": 216851,
              "count": 7853,
              "count_norm": 140019,
              "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 976,
              "parent": 68336,
              "count": 26028,
              "count_norm": 464081,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroidetes",
              "tax_rank": "phylum"
            }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
        {
          "taxon": 817,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 72,
          "count_norm": 1283,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 818,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 208,
          "count_norm": 3708,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 820,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 41,
          "count_norm": 731,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 821,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 3490,
          "count_norm": 62226,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 823,
          "parent": 375288,
          "count": 120,
          "count_norm": 2139,
          "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 832,
          "parent": 204431,
          "count": 12,
          "count_norm": 213,
          "tax_name": "Fibrobacter",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 841,
          "parent": 186803,
          "count": 1285,
          "count_norm": 22911,
          "tax_name": "Roseburia",
          "tax_rank": "genus"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 842,
          "parent": 841,
          "count": 11,
          "count_norm": 196,
          "tax_name": "Roseburia cecicola",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 853,
          "parent": 216851,
          "count": 7853,
          "count_norm": 140019,
          "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 976,
          "parent": 68336,
          "count": 26028,
          "count_norm": 464081,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroidetes",
          "tax_rank": "phylum"
        }
      ]
    }]
```

Here is what I am hoping to achieve if the filter parameter was tax_rank = species:

```
let data = [
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
            {
              "taxon": 817,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 72,
              "count_norm": 1283,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 818,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 208,
              "count_norm": 3708,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 820,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 41,
              "count_norm": 731,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 821,
              "parent": 816,
              "count": 3490,
              "count_norm": 62226,
              "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 823,
              "parent": 375288,
              "count": 120,
              "count_norm": 2139,
              "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 842,
              "parent": 841,
              "count": 11,
              "count_norm": 196,
              "tax_name": "Roseburia cecicola",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            },
            {
              "taxon": 853,
              "parent": 216851,
              "count": 7853,
              "count_norm": 140019,
              "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
              "tax_rank": "species"
            }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
      "ubiome": [
        {
          "taxon": 817,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 72,
          "count_norm": 1283,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 818,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 208,
          "count_norm": 3708,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 820,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 41,
          "count_norm": 731,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 821,
          "parent": 816,
          "count": 3490,
          "count_norm": 62226,
          "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 823,
          "parent": 375288,
          "count": 120,
          "count_norm": 2139,
          "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 842,
          "parent": 841,
          "count": 11,
          "count_norm": 196,
          "tax_name": "Roseburia cecicola",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        },
        {
          "taxon": 853,
          "parent": 216851,
          "count": 7853,
          "count_norm": 140019,
          "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
          "tax_rank": "species"
        }
      ]
    }]
```

Comment: based on data you shown what output is expected?

Comment: If the drop down passes a value of say "species", return the same object structure but with only those objects with a "tax_rank" of "species".

Comment: It looks like you've posted invalid json. Right now data is two objects combined with a comma. I'm guessing you want it to be an array?

Comment: Sorry, it should be wrapped in a bracket.  I copied over from something I was trying to play with.  Should be updated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi bambam, I updated my question with an expected output.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use underscore, it's shorter with plain js.

```js
data.forEach(e => e.ubiome = e.ubiome.filter(e => e.tax_rank === 'species'));

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script>
let data = [
  {
    "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [
      {
        "taxon": 817,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 72,
        "count_norm": 1283,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 818,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 208,
        "count_norm": 3708,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 820,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 41,
        "count_norm": 731,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 821,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 3490,
        "count_norm": 62226,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 823,
        "parent": 375288,
        "count": 120,
        "count_norm": 2139,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 832,
        "parent": 204431,
        "count": 12,
        "count_norm": 213,
        "tax_name": "Fibrobacter",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 841,
        "parent": 186803,
        "count": 1285,
        "count_norm": 22911,
        "tax_name": "Roseburia",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 842,
        "parent": 841,
        "count": 11,
        "count_norm": 196,
        "tax_name": "Roseburia cecicola",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 853,
        "parent": 216851,
        "count": 7853,
        "count_norm": 140019,
        "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 976,
        "parent": 68336,
        "count": 26028,
        "count_norm": 464081,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroidetes",
        "tax_rank": "phylum"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sample_date": "2017-07-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "ubiome": [
      {
        "taxon": 817,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 72,
        "count_norm": 1283,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides fragilis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 818,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 208,
        "count_norm": 3708,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides thetaiotaomicron",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 820,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 41,
        "count_norm": 731,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides uniformis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 821,
        "parent": 816,
        "count": 3490,
        "count_norm": 62226,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroides vulgatus",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 823,
        "parent": 375288,
        "count": 120,
        "count_norm": 2139,
        "tax_name": "Parabacteroides distasonis",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 832,
        "parent": 204431,
        "count": 12,
        "count_norm": 213,
        "tax_name": "Fibrobacter",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 841,
        "parent": 186803,
        "count": 1285,
        "count_norm": 22911,
        "tax_name": "Roseburia",
        "tax_rank": "genus"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 842,
        "parent": 841,
        "count": 11,
        "count_norm": 196,
        "tax_name": "Roseburia cecicola",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 853,
        "parent": 216851,
        "count": 7853,
        "count_norm": 140019,
        "tax_name": "Faecalibacterium prausnitzii",
        "tax_rank": "species"
      },
      {
        "taxon": 976,
        "parent": 68336,
        "count": 26028,
        "count_norm": 464081,
        "tax_name": "Bacteroidetes",
        "tax_rank": "phylum"
      }
    ]
  }];

</script>
```

IMHO underscore/lodash were more important before plain js had the exact same functions, most is now on the Array.prototype which makes it much easier to chain, clearer to read, ... using plain JavaScript.